# 'ClearContents' and 'PasteSpecial' performance

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA I need to clear a very large named range of content (but not formats) and then paste into a part of it formulas taken from a different named range.  The issue is the performance of the clear and then paste operations.  They are quite slow.  However the same operations performed manually on the sheet are significantly faster.  The sheet is always in manual calculation mode.  Below is the code I have written for this:

```
Sub loadFormuals_(nm_rng_formula As String, nm_rng_control As String, nm_rng_paste As String, nm_rng_clear As String)
Dim rAbs As Integer
Dim rRel As Integer

Dim rng_formula As Range: Set rng_formula = Range(nm_rng_formula)
Dim rng_control As Range: Set rng_control = Range(nm_rng_control)
Dim rng_paste As Range: Set rng_paste = Range(nm_rng_paste)
Dim rng_clear As Range: Set rng_clear = Range(nm_rng_clear)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(rng_paste.Worksheet.Name)
ws.EnableCalculation = False
rng_clear.ClearContents


If Not (IsEmpty(rng_control.Cells(1, 1))) Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rAbs = rng_control.End(xlDown).Row
    rRel = rAbs - rng_control.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1
    rng_formula.Copy
    ws.Range(rng_paste.Cells(1, 1), rng_paste.Cells(rRel, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
ws.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

Here `nm_rng_clear` is the string name of the range that needs to be cleared, `nm_rng_formula` is the name of the range with the formulas, and ranges `nm_rng_control` and `nm_rng_paste`control where the formulas are pasted.

The slow parts are:

```
rng_clear.ClearContents
```

and:

```
ws.Range(rng_paste.Cells(1, 1), rng_paste.Cells(rRel, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

Is there anything I can do to make this quicker?

Comment: I tried your method on ranges of more than 1.6M cells with simple but big formulas (=someCell +1+1+1+1+1.. 20 times). Well, it is not that slow after all, takes a few seconds, 10s or less. Tried different things but could not have it faster. All I could say, my feeling is that you might have complex formulas that take too long to calculate. p.s.: I have 4GB memory on my  laptop.

Comment: I am wondering if you could post a sample of your workbook. I do not see any major things that could cause a huge delay.

Comment: Hi. My range has about 3500 rows and about 500 column.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code a tiny bit and I think it will perform a little bit better but it's hard to say. Something that could be slowing down your workbook are large reference formulas using whole columns: VLOOKUP, MATCH... or in some rare cases conditions =IF(A:A=2,A:A-B:B,A:A*C:C)

```
Option Explicit

Sub loadFormuals_(ByVal nm_rng_formula As String, _
                  ByVal nm_rng_control As String, _
                  ByVal nm_rng_paste As String, _
                  ByVal nm_rng_clear As String)

    Dim rAbs As Integer
    Dim rRel As Integer
    Dim strFormula As String

    Call TurnExtrasOff

    Dim rng_formula As Range: Set rng_formula = Range(nm_rng_formula)
    Dim rng_control As Range: Set rng_control = Range(nm_rng_control)
    Dim rng_paste As Range: Set rng_paste = Range(nm_rng_paste)
    Dim rng_clear As Range: Set rng_clear = Range(nm_rng_clear)


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(rng_paste.Worksheet.Name)
    strFormula = rng_formula.Resize(1, 1).Formula

    'Clear the range
    rng_clear.Value = vbNullString

    ' Paste the formulas
    If Not (IsEmpty(rng_control.Cells(1, 1))) Then
        rAbs = rng_control.End(xlDown).Row
        rRel = rAbs - rng_control.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1
        ws.Range(rng_paste.Cells(1, 1), rng_paste.Cells(rRel, 1)).Formula = strFormula
    End If

    Call TurnExtrasOn

End Sub

Sub TurnExtrasOff()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub

Sub TurnExtrasOn()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Dude in the experience i had done, with a huge range, I found `a. Copy : b.PasteSpecial xlFormulas` clearly faster than `b.Formula = a.Formula`. This is why I did not recommend the latter to the OP. Did you make a similar experiment and found the opposite?

Comment: ASH. Thanks a lot for the comment. I do not use a lot of copying formulas so I have to say that my experience with them is limited, After you comment I went ahead and did quite a few experiments and found out that indeed a.formula=b.formula is slower than copying and pasting formulas  Complete Equal = 5.14;  Complete PasteFormula = 2.719;  Complete WriteFormula = 1.797 Also I found that the fastest way to write the formulas is to do so directly rather than coping from another source.